# Is there a easy way to bulk set subfolder permissions in google drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a folder that contains over 1000 subfolders. I want to set the permission to shared to all the subfolders so I tried selecting all and right click then get share link but it didn't work cause it gave error: Too many files

Is there another way to set all the subfolders to shared?

Comment: In your situation, when you set the permissions to a folder including a lot of folders, such error occurs. If my understanding is correct, as a workaround, how about setting it by splitting folders using a script? I think that [the batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) is suitable for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I have no programming knowledge I was hoping for a easier method for a person who doesn't know how to code

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. By the way, can you provide the detail information about ``a easier method`` you think? Because I thought that you are thinking the possibility of use the script and Drive API from your tags. Providing more information will help users think of about your issue. If you can do, please update your question by including the information.

Comment: @Tanaike I can use a script if it just a simple copy & paste

Comment: Do you wish to share all 1000 subfolders with the same user or list of users? And what type of permissions do you wish to give them?

Comment: @Cooper I just want to share to the public

Comment: Are you in a domain?

Comment: Do you want to give them edit access? or read only?

Comment: @Cooper just read only and I'm not in a domain

Comment: @Tanaike if your out there can you take a look at my answer to insure I'm not causing any problems with my answer.

Comment: @Cooper I think that the advantage of your answer is not to use the quotas of Drive API. What I'm worry is about the process cost. Although this should be tried at OP's environment, when the permissions of more than 1000 folders are modified, the cost will be high. If the execution time is over 6 min, it is required to use ``getContinuationToken()``. So I had proposed to use the batch request which can be run with the asynchronous processing. Also when the batch request and fetchAll method are combined, the cost will be much lower. If this was not the reply to your comment, I apologize.

Comment: @TravelWhere Can I ask you about the folder structure of your situation? Are there several subfolders under a subfolder?

Comment: @Tanaike it's just parent > subfolder > file

Comment: @TravelWhere Thank you. In your case, Cooper's current-answer might be able to be used. But I'm not sure whether all folders can be modified by one run. About this, you can see at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132313/is-there-a-easy-way-to-bulk-set-subfolder-permissions-in-google-drive?noredirect=1#comment97012606_55132313). So as the methods for testing, I proposed 2 patterns. Please check [my comment to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132313/is-there-a-easy-way-to-bulk-set-subfolder-permissions-in-google-drive?noredirect=1#comment97012908_55134455).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I think this will give anyone readonly access

To all of the subfolders under the parentFolder with the Id that you put into where it says 'Your Folder ID'.

```
function shareFolders() {
  var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Your Folder ID');
  var subfolders=parentFolder.getFolders();
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    subfolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  }
}
```

I don't have a clue as to how long this will take for 1000 sub folders.

Comment: As the methods for testing the script, how about the following 2 patterns? 1. Split subfolders and put several folders in a folder. By this, the permissions of several folders can be modified by each folder. 2. Declare the limitation time and use ``getContinuationToken()``. By this, even if all folders cannot be modified in one execution, the work can be finished by several running the script.

Answer (score 2):

Setting permission on the parent folder will set permissions on its contents, including subfolders.  If you have mixed settings where subfolders or files do not have the same permissions as the top parent folder you could revoke the permission on the parent folder, then recreate the share setting which will "refresh" permission on all contents.

You could also use a function.  For example, to make a folder and all its contents public:

```
function makeFolderPublic(parentFolderID) {
  var shareThisFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID);
  shareThisFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); // make folder and all its contents public
}
```